# numbers near underflow limit display as `Inf.e-324` in tibble?

Tags: r, floating-point, tibble, underflow

Per the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/zMachine.html), "on a typical R platform the smallest positive double is about `5e-324`." Given a double vector with values above, near, and below this limit:

```r
library(tibble)

small_vec <- c(4e-300, 4e-324, 4e-350)
small_df <- data.frame(x = small_vec)
small_tibble <- tibble(x = small_vec)
```

Printing `small_vec` and `small_df` give about what I'd expect:

```r
small_vec
#> [1] 4.000000e-300 4.940656e-324  0.000000e+00

small_df
#>               x
#> 1 4.000000e-300
#> 2 4.940656e-324
#> 3  0.000000e+00
```

The second value isn't quite right, which I vaguely understand is due to floating point weirdness. The third number underflows to `0`. Fine. But printing as a tibble,

```r
small_tibble
#> # A tibble: 3 × 1
#>           x
#>       <dbl>
#> 1   4 e-300
#> 2 Inf.e-324
#> 3   0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I'm thrown by `Inf.e-324` -- both the idea of `Inf` with an exponent, and the decimal point. What does this signify? Or is it possibly a bug in the tibble package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(A little long for a comment.)

Sure seems like a bug, but I think it's not in `tibble` *per se*, but in the `pillar` package underneath. `library(pillar); pillar_shaft(small_vec)` shows the same pathology. Digging down: looking at `pillar:::format.pillar_shaft_decimal()`, it uses the `$sci` component of this object. That component looks fishy:

```
> pillar_shaft(small_vec)$sci

[harmless-looking stuff]

$lhs
[1] "4"   "Inf" "0"  

$lhs_zero
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE

$rhs
[1]   0 NaN   0

[harmless-looking stuff]
```

So we probably have to see what `pillar_shaft` is doing during the conversion.

Specifically in

```r
pillar:::pillar_shaft_number_attr(small_vec, NULL, NULL)
```

which goes to `pillar_shaft_number` which *seems* to lead to

```r
pillar:::split_decimal(small_vec, sigfig = 3, digits = NULL)
```

but, weirdly enough, that one looks OK, so I must have lost the plot somewhere.

Comment: I just filed a bug report [here](https://github.com/r-lib/pillar/issues/615), if you'd like to add this as a comment.

Comment: A fix is incoming: https://github.com/r-lib/pillar/pull/619.

Comment: Will be fixed in pillar 1.8.2, for now use `devtools::install_github("r-lib/pillar")` .

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug report filled in github. In the meantime, this (not exhaustively tested) hack could work:

```r
library(tibble)

print(tibble(x = c(4e-300, 4e-324, 4e324, 10, -10, 4e-350)))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 1
#>           x
#>       <dbl>
#> 1   4 e-300
#> 2 Inf.e-324
#> 3 Inf      
#> 4   1 e+  1
#> 5  -1 e+  1
#> 6   0

assignInNamespace("safe_divide_10_to", 
                  function(x,y) 10^(log10(x) - y), "pillar")

print(tibble(x = c(4e-300, 4e-324, 4e324, 10, -10, 4e-350)))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 1
#>             x
#>         <dbl>
#> 1   4   e-300
#> 2   4.94e-324
#> 3 Inf        
#> 4   1   e+  1
#> 5  -1   e+  1
#> 6   0
```